# Common SDK Using Swift and Pods

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hi i want create one Common SDK for 3 Project which have same functionality in it but for creating that SDK we need to use some of the pod and bridging header file
we faced issue with how to configure that SDK with pod and bridging header which is used in all 3 apps to work on

Please help me how can we achieve this.

i have tried to add pod with bridging header but some how pod and bridging header not working

Answer (score 2):

You can create framework project with pods and third-party library.

**Note:** You can't use bridging headers within a framework.

There are 2 Solution.
**1. umbrella header
2. module map**

**Solution 1 (umbrella header):**

1. To include the required Obj-C header you need to set it as Public: select it in the project explorer (left pane) and change the property Target Membership (left—Inspectors—pane) from Project to Public.

**[Target Membership Public]**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P26rx.png

2. Open umbrella header (.h) and import the required header as:

**[Import Headers in umbrella header]**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEsLG.png)

This effectively makes this header public and available to both your own framework and anyone who uses it.

**Note:** If you import the header as a local file, i.e. in quotes, e.g. #import "objc-header.h", you likely to hit the compiler error telling you are trying to include a non-modular header.

**Solution 2 (module map):**

Create a file named module.modulemap in the root of your project with the following contents:

[module.modulemap]

```
framework module FrameworkName {
   umbrella header "FrameworkName.h"

   header "objc-header.h"

   export *
   module * { export * }
}
```

In case you want to keep the definitions from objc-header.h private from the users of your framework you can add private qualifier like so:

```
 // ...
private header "objc-header.h"
// ...
```

In Build Setting set Module Map File to module.modulemap

Clean the build directory (⇧⌘K) and build the project (⌘B)